# TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '..._styledComponents.default.button...')

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I am getting this error while using `styled-components` in react native project.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '..._styledComponents.default.button...')
```

Here is my code;

```
import styled from "styled-components";
const Buttonn = styled.button`
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  bordercolor: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  &:hover {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
`;

function CourierDetails() {
  return (
  <Buttonn>Submit</Buttonn>
)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*styled.button* works in React (web), if you want to style a Button in React-native, you have to use Button component provided by react-native.

Also you have to import styled component from 'styled-components/native'

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native'
```

You can create a CustomButton component as Below

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const CustomButton = props => (
    <ButtonContainer
        onPress={() => alert('Hi!')}
        backgroundColor={props.backgroundColor}
    >
        <ButtonText textColor={props.textColor}>{props.text}</ButtonText>
</ButtonContainer>
);

export default CustomButton;

const ButtonContainer = styled.TouchableOpacity`
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 10px;    
    background-color: ${props => props.backgroundColor}; 
`;

const ButtonText = styled.Text`
    font-size: 15px;
    color: ${props => props.textColor};
    text-align: center;
`;
```

Hope this answer helps you, Thank you!